# Assumptions and Conditions in Integrate Function in Mathmatica

Tags: assumptions

I was trying to Integrate the gravitational potential at r = x produced by a uniform sphere positioned at the origin. I wrote the following code:

```
potentialOfSphere[x_] = Integrate[
  Integrate[
  Integrate[
  -m/(4/3 Pi r^3)*g/Sqrt[(x-r1 Cos[ϕ])^2+(r1 Sin[ϕ])^2]*r1^2 Sin[ϕ], 
  {ϕ, 0, Pi}], 
  {θ, 0, 2 Pi}], {r1, 0, r}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, r > 0}]
```

The output on my computer is:

[image]

Based on my understanding, the second solution should only appear when x < r. Why does Mathematica skip that condition? Moreover, in the assumptions in my code, I already specified that x > 0, why does Mathematica still keep the x <= 0 condition in the first solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second solution _does_ only appear when `x<r`. Because if that was not so, the condition for the first solution would be satisfied. AFAIK, the option `Assumptions` does not mean "give solutions restricted to a specific domain", rather it prevents the output of long constructions with `ConditionalExpression`. I'd be hard pressed to elaborate further though.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thank you! I understand why won't it work now. Is there any way to let Mathematica to give solutions restricted to a specific domain?

Comment: I can direct you to the documentation for [Refine](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html), but I'm afraid, I can't test this out myself right now, as I don't have Mathematica at home.

Comment: FYI your `Assumptions` only apply to the outermost  `Integrate`.  Try setting `$Assumptions` (or better make it one triple integral). (cant test here,,) Also if all else fails you can wrap the whole thing in `Simplify` with your assumptions as an argument.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks! I found `Refine` function really helpful.

Comment: @george2079 I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
potentialOfSphere[x_] = Integrate[
  -m/(4/3 Pi r^3)*g/Sqrt[(x - r1 Cos[ϕ])^2 +
      (r1 Sin[ϕ])^2]*r1^2 Sin[ϕ],
  {r1, 0, r}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi},
  Assumptions -> {x > 0, r > 0}]
```

> (g*m*(-2*r^3 + (r - x)^2*(2*r + x)*
>              HeavisideTheta[r - x]))/    (2*r^3*x)

For x > r, this reduces to

```
potentialOfSphere[x] // Simplify[#, x > r] &
```

> -((g*m)/x)

For x < r, this reduces to

```
potentialOfSphere[x] // Simplify[#, r > x] &
```

> (g*m*(-3*r^2 + x^2))/(2*r^3)

For x == r

```
potentialOfSphere[r]
```

> -((g*m)/r)